# Is it possible to automatically jump to the beginning of the help function output within the python console?

Tags: python, console, helper

Every time I use the help function in the python console, I have to scroll up and look for the exact place where the help text starts.

Is there a way to make the cursor jump directly to this position?

Answer (score 0):

You press the letter `g`.

The bindings for the python help text can be found in the `less` command manual, in the `COMMANDS` section. You can access this manual by running `man less` in a shell if you're running Linux.

Comment: This does not work for Windows does it? Do you have an idea how to solve this problem when you are using the Python Console in PyCharm?

Comment: @zwithouta I couldn't say. Haven't tried using Pycharm. However, here's the `less` manual: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/less.1.html . You could try some commands to see if they work inside of help text.